# How to parse attribute values from simple XML to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I am looking to convert the following XML into a `pandas` `dataframe`.

You can view the XML here:

https://clients2.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=how%20garage%20doors

Here is the python 3 code here, which currently returns an empty dataframe.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://clients2.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=how%20garage%20doors')

bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, ['xml'])
print(bs)


obs = bs.find_all("CompleteSuggestion")

print(obs)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['suggestion data','Keyword'])

for node in obs:
    df = df.append({'suggestion data': node.get("suggestion data")}, ignore_index=True)
    
df.head()
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. I am open to do it with other modules if there are any better alternatives.

Also the expected output would be a dataframe containing a list of autosuggest search terms related to "garage doors".

I could not get python `ElementTree` XML conversion to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the attribute of `suggestion` tag, not the text/string inside the tag. Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['suggestion data','Keyword'])

for node in obs:
  for suggestion in node:
    df = df.append({'suggestion data': suggestion.attrs['data']}, ignore_index=True)
df.head()
```

Comment: Hello @jiayu thanks for the tips. it works. I would plus one it but I don't have enough StackOverflow points.

Answer (score 0):

I always use ElementTree to parse an xml, this should work for you.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('YOUR_DATA.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

df = pd.DataFrame()
for child in root:
    for child2 in child:
        line = child2.attrib
        df = df.append(line, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Such a xml structure can be read by pandas `read_xml()`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://clients2.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=how%20garage%20doors')

df = pd.read_xml(response.content, xpath=".//CompleteSuggestion/suggestion", attrs_only=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                data
0              how garage doors work
1          how garage doors are made
2     how garage doors are installed
3     what garage doors are the best
4                  what garage doors
5      how garage door opener remote
6             how garage door opener
7        how garage door maintenance
8             how garage door keypad
9  how garage door weather stripping
```

Comment: Hello @Hermann12, thanks for your suggestion, a nice solution to the problem.

Comment: If you like it, please mark the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 2**: With your `BeautifulSoup` solution. I suggest only one column.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://clients2.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=how%20garage%20doors')

bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml') 

obs = bs("suggestion")
data =[]
for tag in obs:
    data.append(tag.attrs) #get('data')

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['data'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                data
0              how garage doors work
1          how garage doors are made
2     how garage doors are installed
3     what garage doors are the best
4                  what garage doors
5      how garage door opener remote
6             how garage door opener
7        how garage door maintenance
8             how garage door keypad
9  how garage door weather stripping
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have included `pandas`, keep it as simple as possible and use   [`pandas.read_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) and `xpath` parameter to get your goal and the attribute values in to lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_xml('https://clients2.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&output=toolbar&q=how%20garage%20doors',xpath="//suggestion")
```

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | how garage doors work |
| 1 | how garage doors are made |
| 2 | how garage doors are installed |
| 3 | what garage doors are the best |
| 4 | what garage doors |
| 5 | how garage door opener remote |
| 6 | how garage door opener |
| 7 | how garage door maintenance |
| 8 | how garage door keypad |
| 9 | how garage door weather stripping |

Comment: hello @HedgeHow, thanks for refining my question and your reply. This is the best solution. Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to vote on the answer.